# Python Pandas: Create cumulative average while grouping by other column

Tags: python, pandas

Imagine a table like this:

```
name | value 
-----|------
Jack | 0    
Jack | 1
Jack | 0.5
Jack | 1
Jill | 0
Jill | 2
```

For every name, I'd like to have the cumulative average, like this:

```
name | value | cumAverage
-----|-------|-----------
Jack | 0     | 0
Jack | 1     | 0.5
Jack | 0.5   | 0.5
Jack | 1     | 0.625
Jill | 0     | 0
Jill | 2     | 1
```

So whenever a new name appears, the cumulative average should "restart".
The name column is sorted, so whenever a new name appears the current cumulative average is finished.

Comment: You should include code showing what you have attempted. Also, aren't some of your averages wrong (4th and 5th)?

Comment: sorry, I corrected the mistake, to the code - well pandas is mostly done with one-liners, I know that there is cumsum() which addresses a similar problem, but computing the sum, not the average (I could then divide this by another help column that just counts how often the current name occured) but I don't know how to possibly "reset" the cumulative average whenever a new name occurs

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need [`expanding().mean()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.expanding.html) with groupby:

```
df.groupby('name')['value'].expanding().mean().reset_index(0)
```

For Unsorted df the below will work:

```
df.groupby('name')['value'].expanding().mean().reset_index(0).sort_index()
```

---

```
   name  value
0  Jack  0.000
1  Jack  0.500
2  Jack  0.500
3  Jack  0.625
4  Jill  0.000
5  Jill  1.000
```

Answer (score 4):

This will work even if the names are not sorted by [transforming](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) the `expanding` function..

```
>>> df.assign(cumAverage=df.groupby('name', sort=False)['value'].transform(lambda x: x.expanding().mean()))
   name  value  cumAverage
0  Jack    0.0       0.000
1  Jack    1.0       0.500
2  Jack    0.5       0.500
3  Jack    1.0       0.625
4  Jill    0.0       0.000
5  Jill    2.0       1.000

# Unsorted dataframe.
df = pd.DataFrame({"name": ['Jack'] * 3 + ['Jill'] * 2 + ['Jack'], "value": [0, 1, .5, 0, 2, 1]})
>>> df.assign(cumAverage=df.groupby('name', sort=False)['value'].transform(lambda x: x.expanding().mean()))
   name  value  cumAverage
0  Jack    0.0       0.000
1  Jack    1.0       0.500
2  Jack    0.5       0.500
3  Jill    0.0       0.000
4  Jill    2.0       1.000
5  Jack    1.0       0.625
```