# Finding an average per item and ID through time (Python)

Tags: python, pandas

The question is as follows. Suppose I have a data frame like this:

| item | event | sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 130 |
| 1 | B | 156 |
| 1 | C | 108 |
| 2 | B | 150 |
| 2 | D | 118 |
| ... | ... | ... |

In this data frame, event `A` is first in time, then B, then C and so forth.
I now want an average per item-id combination through time.
This means that for item 1 event A, the average is simply 130. For item 1 and event B, the average should be (130+156)/2 = 143. But for item 2, event B, the average is 150 and for item 2 and event D, the average is (130+118)/2 = 124.

So the outcome should look like this:

| item | event | sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 130 |
| 1 | B | 143 |
| 1 | C | 131.33 |
| 2 | B | 150 |
| 2 | D | 124 |
| ... | ... | ... |

Is this possible without a loop? Can we do this with a group by somehow?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems to be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56911611/python-pandas-create-cumulative-average-while-grouping-by-other-column

Comment: @sholderbach ah thanks, missed that completely!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Expanding.mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.window.Expanding.mean.html) with [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) for remove first level of `MultiIndex` for correct align to new column:

```
df['new'] = df.groupby('item')['sales'].expanding().mean().reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
print (df)
   item event  sales         new
0     1     A    130  130.000000
1     1     B    156  143.000000
2     1     C    108  131.333333
3     2     B    150  150.000000
4     2     D    118  134.000000
```

Comment: dude, you are God