# How can I determine the average of a column up to this point, using groupby?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data frame:

| HorseId | FGrating | Average FGrating |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1736 | 110 | -1 |
| 1736 | 124 | -1 |
| 1736 | 118 | -1 |
| 13973 | 144 | -1 |
| 13973 | 137 | -1 |

I want to fill the `Average FGrating` column with the average FGrating of every horse up to the point it was computed, grouped by `HorseId`. The result that I am looking for is this:

| HorseId | FGrating | Average FGrating |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1736 | 110 | 110 |
| 1736 | 124 | 117 (110+124)/2 |
| 1736 | 118 | 117.3 (110+124+118)/3 |
| 13973 | 144 | 144 |
| 13973 | 137 | 140.5 (144+137)/2 |

The code I used to solve this problem is:

```
featured_data['Average FGrating'] = featured_data[['HorseId', 'FGrating']].groupby('HorseId')[
    'FGrating'].mean()
```

However, it computes the desired average in only a part of the data frame not in all of it.

What am I doing wrong? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56911611/python-pandas-create-cumulative-average-while-grouping-by-other-column) for a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can start by grouping by `HorseId` and then get the `cumsum` of `FGrating`. To get the average, we just need to divide the `cumsum` with a `cumcount` like so :

```py
>>> df_grouped =  df.groupby('HorseId')['FGrating']
>>> df['cum_sum'] = df_grouped.apply(lambda p: p.shift(fill_value=0).cumsum())
>>> df['cum_mean'] = df['cum_sum'] / df_grouped.cumcount()
>>> df['cum_mean'].fillna(df['FGrating'], inplace=True)
>>> df
    HorseId     FGrating    Average FGrating    cum_sum     cum_mean
0   1736        110         -1                  0           110.0
1   1736        124         -1                  110         110.0
2   1736        118         -1                  234         117.0
3   13973       144         -1                  0           144.0
4   13973       137         -1                  144         144.0
```

Or we can also do it this way (shorter) :

```py
df['cum_mean'] = (
    df.groupby('HorseId')['FGrating'].apply(lambda x: x.shift().expanding().mean()))
```