# What is the difference between these two code lines?

Tags: python, pandas

I wanted to apply the solutions found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69953294/how-can-i-determine-the-average-of-a-column-up-to-this-point-using-groupby) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56911611/python-pandas-create-cumulative-average-while-grouping-by-other-column) for a problem I had. I wrote a function that had the following return line (aka line 1):

```
return df.loc[mask].groupby('HorseId')['Plassering'].apply(lambda x: x.shift().expanding().mean())
```

I tried to remove the `apply` function, rewriting the above line like this (aka line 2):

```
return df.loc[mask].groupby('HorseId')['Plassering'].shift().expanding().mean()
```

However, the second line completely ignored the `groupby` part and computed the average for the entire dataset. The first line worked perfectly.

What is the difference between line 1 and line 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first version, the function specified inside `.apply()` is applied to each group, the results are combined into a single dataframe and returned. In effect, `.shift().expand().mean()` is computed for each group separately.

In the second version `.shift()` is applied to a groupby object. This shifts each group, assembles the groups into a single dataframe, and returns this dataframe. The following methods `.expanding().mean()` are applied to the whole dataframe.

Comment: Very comprehensive explanation. Thank you!