# Pandas: Create cumulative average based on groupby?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, average

Imagine a table like this:

```
id  country id_col  name    week_start  week_end   result   
0   A       MTR0     R      1/3/2022    1/9/2022    1
1   A       MTR0     R      1/10/2022   1/16/2022   4
2   B       MTR0     R      1/17/2022   1/23/2022   5
```

I want to calculate the cumulate average based on groupby
I tried the below code, but it is throwing an error

```
df.assign(average=df.groupby('country','id_col','name','week_start','week_end', sort=False)['result'].transform(lambda x: x.expanding().mean()))

df['average'] = df.groupby('country','id_col','name','week_start','week_end')['result'].expanding().mean().reset_index(0).sort_index()
```

ERROR:

```
No axis named id_col for object type DataFrame  
No axis named name for object type DataFrame
```

Also tried below code:

```
cum_avg = (df.groupby(['country','id_col','name','week_start','week_end'])['result']
.agg(['sum', 'count'])
.groupby(level='country').cumsum())

df = df.join(
             cum_avg['sum'].div(cum_avg['count']).rename('average'),
             on=['country','id_col','name','week_start','week_end']  # align index on columns
            )
```

input dataframe as list:

```
[['antigua', 'MTR001', 'mttr', Timestamp('2022-02-07 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2022-02-13 00:00:00'), 1.53], ['antigua', 'MTR001', 'mttr', Timestamp('2022-02-14 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2022-02-20 00:00:00'), 0.98], ['antigua', 'MTR001', 'mttr', Timestamp('2022-02-21 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2022-02-27 00:00:00'), 0.0], ['antigua', 'MTR001', 'mttr', Timestamp('2022-02-28 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2022-03-06 00:00:00'), 0.0], ['grenada', 'MTR001', 'mttr', Timestamp('2022-02-07 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2022-02-13 00:00:00'), 14.62], ['grenada', 'MTR001', 'mttr', Timestamp('2022-02-14 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2022-02-20 00:00:00'), 0.0], ['grenada', 'MTR001', 'mttr', Timestamp('2022-02-21 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2022-02-27 00:00:00'), 0.0], ['grenada', 'MTR001', 'mttr', Timestamp('2022-02-28 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2022-03-06 00:00:00'), 0.0], ['jamaica', 'MTR001', 'mttr', Timestamp('2022-02-07 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2022-02-13 00:00:00'), 54.32], ['jamaica', 'MTR001', 'mttr', Timestamp('2022-02-14 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2022-02-20 00:00:00'), 27.69]]
```

Answer (score 1):

First test columns names:

```
print (df.columns.tolist())
```

Then IIUC add list for columns in `groupby`:

```
df = df.assign(average=df.groupby(['country','id_col','name','week_start','week_end'], sort=False)['result'].transform(lambda x: x.expanding().mean()))
print (df)
   id country id_col name week_start   week_end  result  average
0   0       A   MTR0    R   1/3/2022   1/9/2022       1        1
1   1       A   MTR0    R  1/10/2022  1/16/2022       4        4
2   2       B   MTR0    R  1/17/2022  1/23/2022       5        5
```

For second solution:

```
df['average'] = df.groupby(['country','id_col','name','week_start','week_end'])['result'].expanding().mean().droplevel([0,1,2,3,4])
print (df)
   id country id_col name week_start   week_end  result  average
0   0       A   MTR0    R   1/3/2022   1/9/2022       1      1.0
1   1       A   MTR0    R  1/10/2022  1/16/2022       4      4.0
2   2       B   MTR0    R  1/17/2022  1/23/2022       5      5.0
```

Comment: Thanks!! @jezrael. First solution worked for me. I've assigned the df to new variable. Now I'm able to get the average.

Comment: But I'm getting the same result in average also. I'm I doing anything wrong, because the average should be in some other values right?

Comment: @Mahilan - because one row per groups. Do you need grouping by all 5 columns?

Comment: yes basically I want to calculate cum average for result based on grouping other columns.

Comment: @Mahilan - yes, but if not duplicated all rows like in sample data then each group has only one row. So you get same ouput because data.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56911611/python-pandas-create-cumulative-average-while-grouping-by-other-column. Then in this case also, they should get the same value right..but average is different here

Comment: @Mahilan - it is expected, because groupby by one column `name` whcih is duplicated. If groups by 5 columns `['country','id_col','name','week_start','week_end']` and get same ouput is seems no duplicted groups, in another words each group has leght `1`

Comment: @Mahilan check it `for name, g in df.groupby(['country','id_col','name','week_start','week_end']): print (g)`

Comment: I have tried in other way. But not sure it is correct or not. Pasted the new code above **"Also tried below code"** section

Comment: @Mahilan - From your data in question not possible. Need sample data with expected ouput - e.g. 10 rows of input data and how should looks correct `average` column. It is only way for found problem.

Comment: I have added the input dataset but not sure about the result

Comment: @Mahilan - hmmm, my opinion is need grouping by one or 2 columns only. Not by all 5 columns. But cannot chceck it because cannot compare expected output. Because is not in question

Comment: Or maybe need grouping by `id  country id_col  name` columnsonly